# BlueIris and Codeproject.AI error while installing module

Tags: xcode-project

```
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: Installing module ObjectDetectionNet                                  
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: Start-BitsTransfer : The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073B01)
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: At line:1 char:1
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: + Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'https://codeproject-ai.s3.ca-central-1.am ...
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], COMException
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Mana 
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet:    gement.NewBitsTransferCommand
21:29:55:ObjectDetectionNet: Downloading ObjectDetectionNet module...An error occurred that could not be resolved.
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: Start-BitsTransfer : The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073B01)
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: At line:1 char:1
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: + Start-BitsTransfer -Source 'https://codeproject-ai.s3.ca-central-1.am ...
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], COMException
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Mana 
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet:    gement.NewBitsTransferCommand
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: Downloading YOLO ONNX models...An error occurred that could not be resolved.
21:29:56:ObjectDetectionNet: Module setup complete                                                 
21:29:56:Module ObjectDetectionNet installed successfully.
21:29:56:Module ObjectDetectionNet not configured to AutoStart.
21:29:56:Installer exited with code 1
21:29:56:Unknown response from server
```

I have searched for hours, but i don't know what to do... Can't get it installed on windows.